# Trying to understand a javascript function that changes html code

Tags: javascript, html

so I have been following a website tutorial on youtube using HTML, CSS, and Javascript, but the instructor does not really elaborate on some of the codes he writes.

Here is the javascript function, PageTransitions(), I'm trying to understand:

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const sectBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".controlls");
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".control");
const allSections = document.querySelector('.main-content');

function PageTransitions() {
    for (let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++) {
        sectBtn[i]. addEventListener("click", function() {
            let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
            currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace("active-btn",'');
            this.className += 'active-btn';
        })
    }
}

PageTransitions();
```

In the HTML code below, when the PageTransitions() function is called, it changes the active-btn class to control-1, control-2, etc, but I do not understand how exactly the javascript function changes the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Portfolio</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/25c3cf235c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body class="main-content">
            <header class="section sec1 header active">
                
            </header>
            <main>
                <section class="section sec2 about"></section>
                <section class="section sec3 portfolio"></section>
                <section class="section sec4 blogs"></section>
                <section class="section sec5 contact"></section>
            </main> 

            <div class="controlls">
                <div class="control control-1 active-btn">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-house-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="control control-2 " data-id ="about">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="control control-3 " data-id ="portfolio">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="control control-4 " data-id ="blogs">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-newspaper"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="control control-5 " data-id ="contact">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src = "app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Why are we choosing sectBtn.length instead of sectBtns.length when we use the for loop here?

```
for (let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++)
```

Also, what exactly this part is doing?

```
sectBtn[i]. addEventListener("click", function() {
    let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
    currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace("active-btn",'');
    this.className += 'active-btn';
```

Can someone please explain the code to me step by step?

Answer (score 0):

> In the HTML code below, when the PageTransitions() function is called, it changes the active-btn class to control-1, control-2, etc, but I do not understand how exactly the javascript function changes the HTML code.

Firstly, the guy created a reference to all elements that have the class named "control". [Read more about querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".control");
```

Because there are multiple elements with a "control" class, `sectBtn` will now become an array with a length, hence its "length" can be used for looping

So after that, he loops through every single element with a 'control' class and add [an Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to each element. This will be listening for some kind of trigger and then it will perform something, in this case will be a "click", hence `addEventListener("click",...` and it will run a `function()`

So inside that `function()`, he basically searched for the element that is having the class name 'active-btn' by using the same `querySelectorAll` and remove the class name from that element, then add the class name 'active-btn'  to the element that has been clicked.